# Conditional anchor links

Tags: html, css

I have a table of contents that then scrolls to the various headings / subheadings.

Now other than the introduction, the other subheadings users need to be logged in to read.

If I use normal anchors, clicking on the heading will throw a 404 error for users... rather than scroll down to the 'Please log in' container.

Is there a simple and clean way to set this up so that if the anchor isn't found it reverts maybe to the container (possibly default anchor)?

// I had a good search around but couldn't find anything specific to this issue.

Comment: You'll have to use `JS` to check if user is logged in then go to that `# anchor`

Comment: Yes, use Javascript to alter the anchors or server-side processing like PHP, ASP.NET or Python to alter these anchors depending on if the user is logged in or not

Comment: how do you keep track of the authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id='title' href='details.html'>Title Only for logged in users</a>
<div id='signIn'>Please sign in</div>
```

In js

```
if(!user.loggedIn){
 document.getElementById('title).setAttribute('href', '#signIn');
}
```